# Is it possible to NULL terminate a 2 dimensional array of C++ structs?

Tags: c++

Good afternoon, Is it possible to NULL terminate a 2 dimensional array of C++ structs? Thank you.

```
sPRIORITYANALYZER sArrayOfArrayAnalyzerArray[3][3] = {
{ 
  {mdMUReadWrite::First,mdProfiler::DataTypeFirstName},
  {mdMUReadWrite::FullName,mdProfiler::DataTypeFullName},
  {mdMUReadWrite::InverseName,mdProfiler::DataTypeInverseName} 
},

{ 
  {mdMUReadWrite::Last,mdProfiler::DataTypeFirstName},
  {mdMUReadWrite::FullName,mdProfiler::DataTypeFullName},
  {mdMUReadWrite::InverseName,mdProfiler::DataTypeInverseName} 
},

{
  {mdMUReadWrite::Zip9,mdProfiler::DataTypeZipOrPostalCode},
  {mdMUReadWrite::Zip5,mdProfiler::DataTypeZipOrPostalCode},
  {mdMUReadWrite::CityStZip,mdProfiler::DataTypeCityStateZip}

}
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by null terminate?

Comment: Luchian Grigore, NULL terminate means that you can iterate through the contents of the 2 dimensional array with a nested pair of for loops. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank Why can't you iterate using the actual size of the array instead of looking for a struct that has somehow been initialized to this *null* value?

Comment: @Praetorian, Yes , I can use the actual size of the array. I agree withyou. However, may I still use a null terminator instead? Thank you.

Comment: sizeof is also useful if you have access the the actual global variable and not a reference to it (sizeof (sArrayOfArrayAnalyzerArray[0]))

Comment: @cppguy, Yes. Sizeof is also useful to access the global C++ variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null termination is only meaningful if you have an array of pointers.  You'll have to put a complete empty row there:

```
{ { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } }
```

Luckily, C and C++ let you get away with just a single initialization, so just `{ { 0 } }` should work.  You will need to make your array size be `[4][3]`, too.

Comment: +1 This will work as long as zero is not a valid value for those structure fields.

Comment: Yup - that's an assumption I was making based on his request for "null" termination.

Comment: @Carl Norum, I just tried { 0, 0, 0} and got the compiler error   error C2078: too many initializers. Thank you

Comment: @Carl Norum I just tried{ { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } } and got the compiler error C2078: too many initializers. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, Frank. I edited my answer.  You need to use a different initializer, and don't forget to change your array dimensions.

Comment: @Carl Norun, You are correct The following code is accepted by the C++ compiler. { { (mdMUReadWrite::MatchcodeMapping)0, (mdProfiler::ProfilerDataType)0 }, { (mdMUReadWrite::MatchcodeMapping)0, (mdProfiler::ProfilerDataType)0 }, {(mdMUReadWrite::MatchcodeMapping) 0, (mdProfiler::ProfilerDataType)0 } } . Thank you. Iam accepting your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening, The folllowing code is the correct proposed answer and compiles on Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 C++ compiler. Thank you.

sPRIORITYANALYZER sArrayOfArrayAnalyzerArray[][4] = {

```
{ 
  {mdMUReadWrite::First,mdProfiler::DataTypeFirstName},
  {mdMUReadWrite::FullName,mdProfiler::DataTypeFullName},
  {mdMUReadWrite::InverseName,mdProfiler::DataTypeInverseName},
  (mdMUReadWrite::MatchcodeMapping)0
},

{ 
  {mdMUReadWrite::Last,mdProfiler::DataTypeFirstName},
  {mdMUReadWrite::FullName,mdProfiler::DataTypeFullName},
  {mdMUReadWrite::InverseName,mdProfiler::DataTypeInverseName},
  (mdMUReadWrite::MatchcodeMapping)0
},

{
  {mdMUReadWrite::Zip9,mdProfiler::DataTypeZipOrPostalCode},
  {mdMUReadWrite::Zip5,mdProfiler::DataTypeZipOrPostalCode},
  {mdMUReadWrite::CityStZip,mdProfiler::DataTypeCityStateZip},
  (mdMUReadWrite::MatchcodeMapping)0

},

{ { (mdMUReadWrite::MatchcodeMapping)0, (mdProfiler::ProfilerDataType)0 }, { (mdMUReadWrite::MatchcodeMapping)0, (mdProfiler::ProfilerDataType)0 }, {(mdMUReadWrite::MatchcodeMapping) 0, (mdProfiler::ProfilerDataType)0 } }
```

};

Comment: @Carl Norum, Please let me know your thoughts on my proposed answer. Thank you,